# Error printing collection.Counter instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

Counter objects are subclasses of dict so they have the method setdefault.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(houses=5)
>>> print(c.setdefault.__doc__)
D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

If I do:

```
>>> c.setdefault('castles')
>>> c.keys()
dict_keys(['castles', 'houses'])
>>> type(c)
<class 'collections.Counter'>
```

everything seems pretty nice. But:

```
>>> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    c
  File "C:\Python32\lib\collections.py", line 586, in __repr__
    items = ', '.join(map('%r: %r'.__mod__, self.most_common()))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\collections.py", line 477, in most_common
    return sorted(self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
>>>
```

Is this a bug?. Should not give `c.setdefault('castles')` a value/key error instead of silently accept a key without value ? Or maybe a repr method taking into account None values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, looks like a bug. The problem is that `setdefault` without a value argument assumes the value is `None`, while in the case of a `Counter` it should really insert either one or zero, or fail by raising some exception.

In Python 2.7, your snippet works, btw., although it still inserts a `None` value, violating `Counter`'s invariants.

Mind you, this isn't the first [bug/design flaw](http://bugs.python.org/issue13121) that I encounter with `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Counter was a backport to python 2.7? It is weird it works in 2.7 and fails in py3k.

Comment: @joaquin: well, it fails in 3.2. I haven't checked 3.0 or 3.1.

Comment: It fails in 3.x because many nonsensical comparisions have been disallowed in the process. In 2.x, you can basically compare everything to everything else and get some result (though it's rarely meaningful).

Comment: @joaquin That isn't a *Counter* specific issue.  In Py2.x, ``None < 0`` evaluates to *True*.  In Py3.x, ``None < 0`` raises a *TypeError*.  This change is fundamental to what Python 3 is trying to do.  It was considered a historical mistake that python ever provided cross-type comparison by default.

Comment: No more cross-type comparisons? That's stupid. I used those to implement generic sorted dictionaries. Still, I consider what's happening a `Counter` bug as `setdefault` shouldn't store a `None` in a `Counter`.

Comment: @larmans If you think Guido's design decisions are stupid, then you're using the wrong language.  Just sayin.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: actually, I'm not using Python 3 at all :) I'd love to learn it some day, when the libraries I need have been ported to it.

Answer (score 2):

The  `c.setdefault('castles')` line directly assigns `c['castles'] = None`.  This likely isn't what you intended.

If you intended to make *castles* show in the *__repr__*, use `c['castles'] = 0` instead.

For a *Counter* to behave as designed, the *keys* can be anything you want to count and the *values* need to be a number.  As you've seen, the sort-step in *__repr__* expects that the values are all numbers  and it won't work if one of the values is set to *None*.

It might seem that *setdefault* would be used to give the counter default values or assign a factory function, but that isn't what *setdefault* does.  And you don't need to do that step at all since *Counter* objects automatically return default value of zero for you.  No extra work is required.

Here is how it all works, simply and easily:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(houses=5)
>>> c
Counter({'houses': 5})
>>> c['castles']           # counters automatically return zero for missing items, no work required
0
>>> c                      # but missing items won't show in the __repr__
Counter({'houses': 5})
>>> c['castles'] = 0       # unless you specifically add an entry for them
>>> c
Counter({'houses': 5, 'castles': 0})
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I was just playing with it as a dictionary, not coding anything real, just suggesting this object is "misbehaving". It is a dictionary subclass. I can do this with a normal dictionary, it puts None when no value is given but when I print it I do not get an exception.

Comment: @joaquin It's not "misbehaving". You're not using it as intended and thus you're getting an error. Just don't do it and everything will be fine.

Comment: +1 for showing how counters  returns 0 with unknown keys (logical but not deadly obvious: there are things for which their count is 0 but also there are other things that simply do not exist).

Comment: @yak: if `Counter` is not intended to be used as a `dict`, then it is violating the Liskov substitution principle.